# df.to_csv() giving *** TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get the above error when i try df2.to_csv('abc.csv').

More details:

```
(Pdb) type(df2)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
(Pdb) df2
   0x01  0x03  0x07  0x0f  0x1f  0x3f  0x7f
0     2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    10     2     5     2     4     4   NaN
2    26     4    17    16    25    10     1
3    12    11    25    13    31    21     7
4    10    37    24    22    18    37    33
5    10    39    23    21    13    15    27
6    22     7     5    11     5     3    23
7     8   NaN   NaN     4     3     3     6
8   NaN   NaN     1    11     1     7     3

[9 rows x 7 columns]
(Pdb) df2.to_csv('abc.csv')
*** TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
(Pdb)
```

I am not slicing anything ... so the error makes no sense.

Comment: Could be a bug. Use `pip install --upgrade pandas` and update to the latest version.

Comment: Does the same error happen outside of `pdb`?  If so, edit your question to include the full stacktrace.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that seems to have solved the issue ! Thanks